# Change ToolBar default icon on the left

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar

I am using a ToolBar at the top at present and want to replace the default back button with a home button. But when I add item, it always adds to the right. I don't see any layout_gravity options to choose either. Is there a way to do this?

MainActivity

```
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_delete);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("                Testing");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_icon_empty, menu);
    return true;
}
```

home_icon_empty.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/homepage"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="HOME"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/homepage1"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="HOME"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Current Toolbar output:

[image]

Expected Toolbar output:

[image]

Image after new edit:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set as NavigationIcon:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable)
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: It works but the image size is not properly resized unlike when I am adding items. Anyway around this? Added image for reference.

Comment: It's because your drawable has a lower resolution (in size) that you expect. Menu itens in material is recommended to be 24dp. You can resize it programmatically, or simple put some ImageView inside the `<Toolbar>` in XML

Comment: I see your image. Your icon is too big for the resolution. You need to create a lower size icon. You can do that using this tool: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html

Comment: Did the link helps? Create a new actionbar icon and replace, it should work

Comment: So I should resize it to 48dp x 48dp?

Comment: It's the recommended size for material design... it's up to you =)

Answer (score 2):

You can also:

```
mToolbar.setLogo( yourLogoID );
```

or you can:

```
mToolbar.setBackground( ContextCompat.getDrawable( yourContext, urBackgroundID );
```

where

```
mToolbar = yourToolbar;
mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar);
// or, if your toolbar get setted by a superclass
mToolbar = (Toolbar) getSupportActionBar();
```

your style should be: Blablabla.NoActionBar
then in xml layout include your toolbar

If you are using a Drawer to show left Menu when Left Swiped or Home Button Clicked then you should use one of above methods (If you don't want to superclass all DrawerLayout lul)

bb

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
```

Use it before setting support action bar.
And don't call this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Or at least do

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Try it out. Some of this will work.

Comment: It works but the image size is not properly resized unlike when I am adding items. Anyway around this? Added image for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add your drawable asset  with size  as per [Material design guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar)   and call below method in Activity `onCreate`

```
private void setUpToolBar() {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            //Set Home screen icon
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.home_screen_icon);

            //Enable Home icon
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            //Toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

           //Set toolbar as action bar
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
```