# Change the position of menu item to left side

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar like below picture
[image]

and i want to change it to this
[image]

or this
[image]

Below code is my menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings2"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: So you either setup a navigation button which will allow one button on the top left. or you just make a custom toolbar.

Comment: @NicolasTyler if i make a custom toolbar by adding a button on the left side of toolbar, i need to have a reference to button as MenuItem object so i can link it to material search view. https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView.

Comment: You do not need to have a MenuItem to show a SearchView, but you can if you wish, and you could use the support library SearchView. Im sure you can google how to do these things.

Answer (score 0):

Set as NavigationIcon:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable)
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

*[Taken from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34292878/2664634)*